# Regular Expression to find files with various extensions like-ASPX,ASCX,.js,.rpt,.xml

Tags: regex

Is there any way to write a RegEx which can be used to find files with different Extensions.

Comment: Can you paste an example of string in which you want to search?

Answer (score 3):

This works in `Bash`:

```
find . -regex  '.*\\.\\(pdf\|chm\|doc\\)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is, but the question you should be asking is "What's the best way to find files which have specific extensions?".

Regular expressions are *not* the best answer to every question.

I would suggest just getting a list of all files and passing them into a function like `IsThisFileOneIWant(fileName,extensionList)`. That's far easier than trying to shoehorn the use of regular expressions into your problem.

Something like this should do it:

```
function IsThisFileOneIWant(fileName,extensionList):
    for each extension in extensionList:
        if fileName.endsWith (extension):
            return true
    return false
```

Done in pseudo-code since it should be simple enough to turn into any other language.

If you *must* have a regex, it's going to look something like (based on the values in your question):

```
"ASPX$|ASCX$|\.js$|\.rpt$|\.xml$"
```

but it depends entirely on the RE engine that you want to use. For example, here's the output from an egrep command in my work directory:

```
pax@paxbox1:~/work$ ls -1 | egrep '\.sh$|\.c$'
  backup0.sh
  backup1.sh
  eclipse.sh
  monbt.sh
  qq.c
  qq.sh
  xx yy.sh
```

Comment: I agree with your viewpoint. But in my case regex is the only solution. Kindly help me with my question

Comment: @Pax: For the sake of legibility, I think I'd use this regex: ".\.(aspx|ascx|js|rpt|xml)$". Other than that, I second your first statement. ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of files and you are looking for .pdf, .chm and .doc, you can check it with:

> `\.pdf$|\.chm$|\.doc$`

Regex above should work if you will check it against single filenames.